# method not redirecting to given view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to implement login in codeigniter.
Everything is working fine but when i am entering the correct username and password, it's not redirecting to admin page.
Please Help me, what's going wrong.

login_control

```
class login_control extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

    function verify()
    {

        $query = $this->login_model->login();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('uname','Username','trim|required|min_length[8]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pass','Password','trim|required|max_length[6]');

        if($query)
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('uname'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('admin_control/admin');
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->index();

            }

    }
```

login_model

```
class login_model extends CI_Model
{
    function login()
    {
        $this->db->where('username',  $this->input->post('uname'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('pass')));

        $sql = $this->db->get("signup");
         if($sql->num_rows() == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }

     }

}
```

login_view

```
<body>
<div class="form-wrapper">

  <form action="login_control/verify" method="post">
    <h3>Login here</h3>

    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="text" name="uname" required="required" placeholder="Username" autofocus></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required="required" placeholder="Password"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="button-panel">
        <input type="submit" class="button" title="Log In" value="Login"></input>
    </div>

  </form>

  <div class="reminder">
    <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign up now</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></p>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

admin_control

```
<?php

class admin_control extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->is_logged_in();
    }

    function admin()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin_view');
    }

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $login = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($login) || $login != TRUE)
        {
            echo 'Sorry, you are not a admin. ';
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $sql = $this->db->get("signup"); what are you doing with this line of code ??

Comment: @Drudge
getting signup table in which i saved the username and password from signup form

Comment: Your class and file names should have first letter upper case as shown here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world and here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Comment: @wolfgang1983
I already tried that too but still did not work :(

Comment: What does your url say does it have ip address after the http or localhost?

Comment: If it has your ip address after `http://127.0.0.1/yourproject/` then you need to set your base_url in your config.php file `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983
No, i have no issue in my url as i already have set base_url

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
redirect('admin_control/admin',true);
```

OR

```
redirect('admin_control/admin','refresh');
```

if you not remove index.php

```
redirect('index.php/admin_control/admin',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done some mistake in your `login_model`  while querying database.

Instead of this :

```
class login_model extends CI_Model {

    function login() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('uname'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('pass')));

        $sql = $this->db->get("signup");
        if ($sql->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Use this :

```
class login_model extends CI_Model {

    function login() {
        $this->db->select('id, username, password');
        $this->db->from('signup');
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('uname'));
        $this->db->where('password', MD5($this->input->post('pass'));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $sql = $this->db->get();
        if ($sql->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

For more info see this [doc](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: how can you know, that from which table you are selecting data .. :)

Comment: @santosh on the basis of OP comments. :)

Comment: @Drudge
Santosh is saying right!
..
I have to put value in get().
Anyhow your solution did not work

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide check the answer again i have updated according to your requirement.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide are you getting any errors ?

Comment: @Drudge
Now it's stop giving 404 error but now it's returning back to login page :(

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide if it is redirecting to login page, then it is not problem with redirection, it is the issue of username and password. Check your db username and pass and use that username and pass.

Comment: @Drudge
I recently added a new username and password like 123456. But when i entered it to my login page , it returns back to login page

Comment: In your code, you are checking password with md5, so you should encrypt your password with md5 in your db also.

Answer (score 0):

try rhis

**login_control**

```
public function __construct() 
   {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

    function verify()
    {

        $query = $this->login_model->login();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname','Username','trim|required|min_length[8]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass','Password','trim|required|max_length[6]');

        if($query!= null)
        {
            foreach ($query as $row) 
            {
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $row->username,
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            }
            redirect(base_url('admin_control/admin'),'refresh');
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->index();

        }
```

**model**

```
class login_model extends CI_Model
{
    function login()
    {
        $pass = md5($this->input->post('pass'));
        $this->db->where('username',  $this->input->post('uname'));
        $this->db->where('password',$pass);

        $sql = $this->db->get("signup");
         if($sql->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                   return $query->result();
            }
           else{
                  return false;

     }

}
```

Comment: No, it's not working at all.
It returns back to my login page :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved my problem  !!!!!

I would like to thanks to all participants for answering this question and for their precious time.

Actually, the datatype of the passwd in table was VARCHAR (10). I simply replaced it with VARCHAR (255) and my problem solved !
..

Comment: by removing md5 your problem is not solved. With md5 your verification with user and password with database is failed that why your page was not redirecting. Check your credential if it saving md5 in your database

Comment: @Vinie
without md5 if i try to enter any username and password that is not available in database, it always returns back to my login page. It only goes to admin page if the username and password is 100% matched.
....

Comment: @Vinie
Yes db shows my encrypted password in relevant table

Comment: @Vinie
I solved with md5() too.
See my edited answer.